# Can (CPU) logic and (flash) memory be located on the same die?

Tags: semiconductors

Is it possible to manufacture semiconductors in a way that places logic (for example, a CPU core) on the same die with non-volatile flash (or other EEPROM memory) circuits? What about DRAM?

It certainly seems to be possible to have on-CPU-die SRAM (in the form of various caches); is there a technical reason that DRAM and non-volatile memory can't be included? Is this because SRAM consists of the same or very similar transistors as the CPU logic?

Or is that simply a matter of economics (being able to combine various CPU and memory types without expensive chip redesigns)?

Are there some specialized applications where those different semiconductor types are still combined on the same die because of space requirements (I'm thinking about things like smart cards which contain at least a CPU, ROM and some NVRAM)?

Comment: You mean like in a MCU?

Comment: Do MCUs contain everything on a single die? I was under the impression that a single chip could contain multiple different dies and was wondering whether that was how memory and logic are combined in a MCU.

Comment: Yes they do contain everything on a single die. That is crucial because manufacturing costs would be higher otherwise. You can buy an MCU at under 0.5 GBP, one-off, and have a range of sub-$ device choices.

Comment: It is fairly rare for chips to contain multiple dies.

Answer (score 3):

In answer to your question: YES.

Read [Microcontroller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microcontroller), and you might be pleasantly surprised.

Microcontrollers (MCUs) combine logic (CPUs) with non-volatile Flash memory, RAM, and sometimes EEPROM or FRAM.

MCUs also have digital logic to implement peripheral interfaces, such as SPI, I2C, UART, Timers, USB, CAN, etc. MCUs usually include relatively large current drive capabilities, compared to the transistors internal to the circuitry, in General Purpose I/O which interfaces to the circuitry outside the chips package.

MCU's sometimes contain analogue circuitry such as analogue to digital converters (ADC), operation amplifiers (OpAmps), analogue comparators, digital to analogue converters (DAC).

A more extreme example of integration is Radio. For example, [Atmel](http://www.atmel.com/products/Wireless/802154/single-chip_solutions.aspx), [NXP](http://www.nxp.com/products/microcontrollers/wireless_microcontrollers/#overview), [ST](http://www.st.com/web/en/catalog/sense_power/FM1934/CL1942/SC612/PF253254) and [TI](http://www.ti.com/lit/sg/slab056c/slab056c.pdf) all claim to manufacture single die Radio and MCUs.

Everything is on a single die. That is crucial because manufacturing costs would be higher otherwise. You can buy an MCU at under 0.5 GBP, one-off, and have a range of sub-$ device choices.

The markets for MCUs are diverse and large. However they mostly have one thing in common, the MCU is 'embedded' inside a product. Bringing a mass-market product to market is typically slow and costly, and they are sold as complete, finished, products.

Hence most people are unaware of MCUs, or the MCUs role in the modern products. (I have first-hand experience because I present talks and workshops to the general public, as well as education about exactly these topics.)

Visit a distributers web site, for example [Digikey](http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en/integrated-circuits-ics/embedded-microcontrollers/2556109?k=microcontroller), [Mouser](http://www2.mouser.com/Semiconductors/Integrated-Circuits-ICs/Embedded-Processors-Controllers/Microcontrollers-MCU/_/N-a86ge/), [Farnell](http://uk.farnell.com/microcontrollers-mcu) to get a sense of the range of products. Some of those examples claim to have over 10,000 *different* MCU parts.

Interestingly, the human race manufacture about 30-50 times *more* MCUs (devices which incorporate al of the pieces of functionality) than devices which don't (microprocessors).

I believe the MCU market is as bigger or bigger than the microprocessor market too, though I find it hard to get up-to-date numbers.

Some of the companies which make microcontrollers are listed in [Types of Microcontroller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microcontroller#Types_of_microcontrollers) though that list is incomplete.

Comment: Addressing the extra process complexity for flash (and embedded DRAM, the common term for DRAM in a logic-oriented process) would be appropriate. This increases manufacturing cost (and potentially delays process availability). It might be noted that IBM used embedded DRAM for the on-die L3 cache in POWER7 (where the trench capacitors that allowed the implementation of DRAM were also used to avoid voltage drops during increased power use).

Comment: @PaulA.Clayton - Are you saying IBM makes a POWER7 based MCU?!! If not, what relevance is "It might be noted that IBM used embedded DRAM for the on-die L3 cache in POWER7"?

Comment: The question asks about CPU and NVRAM/DRAM on the same die with an emphasis on the process technology constraints, **not** specifically about *microcontrollers*.

Comment: @PaulA.Clayton - okay, I understand. Maybe you should post an answer explaining that issue? I have no doubt you are correct, however you are clearly more expert than I to explain it.

Answer (score 3):

It is.  Microcontrollers generally contain logic, Flash, and SRAM all on one die.  But they are not designed to be high performance chips, and they are generally made with 'old' processes.

This is generally not done for high performance devices for several reasons.  First is process optimization.  The optimal process characteristics for high performance DRAM, high performance Flash, and high performance logic are generally different and comprimises must be made to combine them on one chip.  Second, yield.  If your RAM array doesn't test out, the chip gets canned even though the flash and logic are good.  So it is generally not done for very complex chips because the yield would be too low to be economical.  It also means that the flash and RAM sizes are fixed so it is not possible to select different sizes of Flash or RAM for different applications.

Flash and RAM also take up a huge amount of silicon area and there is far more demand for flash and RAM than for any given CPU design, so economies of scale drive down the cost flash and RAM chips far more than the CPUs.  Because of this, designers try to make the CPU dies as small as possible to minimize the cost of production - all else being equal, the cost per area of the CPU die will be higher the cost per area of off-the-shelf memory chips.

This is also the main reason devices like FPGAs do not often contain flash memory - it is hard enough to get the programmable logic working that they really don't want to sacrifice yields by adding a flash array that is only used on power up.

Comment: What do you mean by "they are made with 'old' processes"? IIRC ST are using 28nm, TI is on 40nm, and do some 28nm.

Comment: Generally microcontrollers are not built with the 'bleeding edge' process.  28 nm has been around for a while.  Do you know of any microcontrollers currently in 22nm?

Comment: I don't bother tracking process scale as much as capability and cost. IIRC ARM might have done a press release about working with someone on 22nm, but I can't be sure without digging. Is that all "'old' processes" means? I mean, is there nothing between 'bleeding edge' and 'old'? I tend to include 'mature' or 'well understood' in between those, with 'obsolete' somewhere too :-)

Comment: Well, genrally when I think 'MCU' I think AVR and PIC, and these are probably still in the 100s of nm.  Definitely qualifies for 'old'.  I think the majority of MCUs produced probably fall into this category, as most of them are going to be of the lower-performance variety and incpororated into older exisiting designs.  Also, 28nm is also from 2010 or 2011.  So it's a generation or two behind the bleeding edge.

Comment: We have different ways of looking at things. I was just trying to understand yours.